# Port forwarding using SSH with different users: how to debug connection problems?

Tags: server, ssh, vnc

I have a server setup up with Ubuntu 12.10. Got everything working nicely except for one thing: SSH port forwarding.

I use the following command to forward some VNC server to my PC:

```
ssh -L 5900:node:5900 adminuser@server
```

That works very well.

However, this is not true for other users:

```
ssh -L 5900:node:5900 someotheruser@server
```

This user is able to connect to the server (can log in and do something), but the port is **not** forwarded, i.e. `gvncviewer localhost` is not finishing (says *Connected to server*  but never asks for the password).

**What do I have to do in order to allow forwarding for the other (or selected) users as well?**

Edit: Using `ssh -vv ...` I got the following messages when calling `gvncviewer localhost` and having connected using the **adminuser**:

```
debug1: Connection to port 5900 forwarding to 10.100.0.8 port 5900 requested.
debug2: fd 9 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: fd 9 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 3: new [direct-tcpip]
debug2: channel 3: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
... -----> It works
```

For the **someotheruser** I get:

```
debug1: Connection to port 5900 forwarding to 10.100.0.8 port 5900 requested.
debug2: fd 9 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: fd 9 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 3: new [direct-tcpip]
-----> Here it hangs for a long time...
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
debug2: channel 3: zombie
debug2: channel 3: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 5900 for 10.100.0.8 port 5900, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 39009, nchannels 4
```

**Apparently the problem is caused by the VNC server and not by ssh.**

Comment: Try to use `ssh -v` to see if it can help to show the problem. Moreover, ports are global, so I imagine that you are not trying to run the second command while the first one is running (it is not clear in the question).

Comment: I'm trying one or the other command, not both. `ssh -v` gives me `OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012` on the server and `OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013` on my computer

Comment: Sorry I was not clear --- if you use `ssh -v -L 5900:node:5900 someotheruser@server` the command will be verbose and it will comment what is happening --- so it is easier to detect the problem. You can use also `-vv` and `-vvv` to have more debug information.

Comment: Added the requested information in the question.

Comment: It is as the user can't connect (locally) to the port 5900. Try to see if you can connect locally (ssh without the redirection, and in the user shell try `telnet 10.100.0.8 5900`). Be prepared to kill the telnet from another ssh session, it may hang even if it works (if it works it should say something like RFB 003.007 or similar). Check that the VNC server is run by the same user you are trying to connect with.

Comment: The VNC server runs on windows, so neither of the usernames fit here. The `telnet` confirms your assumption, the normal user isn't getting anything while it works for the adminuser. Anyhow, the normal user is able to ping 10.100.0.8.

Comment: Ok --- so the problem is not ssh. You have to find what's happening on the VNC server side --- being Windows I can't help you. Hope this helped anyway.

Comment: That already cleared a lot. They have installed Win 7 on those computers and since then nothing worked. I'm lost when it comes to Win, so I have to see what to do. Thank you.

Comment: I tried to summarize the answer for the posterity. Would you please accept and upvote it so that it will be found on searches? I will edit the title a bit too. (and delete some comment to clean it up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to compose an answer so that we can mark this question solved.

To check the connection, run ssh using one or more `-v` options, like in:

```
ssh -v ...
```

or

```
ssh -vvv ...
```

Checking the log, it is as the user can't connect (locally) to the port 5900.

Try to see if you can connect locally:

```
 ssh someotheruser@server
```

and when you have the user's shell on the server try

```
 telnet 10.100.0.8 5900
```

Be prepared to kill the telnet from another ssh session, it may hang even if it works (if it works it should say something like

```
Trying 10.100.0.8...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
RFB 003.007
```

If it does not connect, the problem is not in ssh port forwarding, is that the VNC server is not accepting connections from the user.